# What are the parameters required for removeValue() and setValue() in DefaultCategoryDataset for jFreeChart?

Tags: java, jfreechart

I'm relatively new to programming, and I'm trying to make a jFreeChart line graph of Lean Body Mass growth, with the lean body mass in kg (y axis) over months (x axis) using DefaultCategoryDataset to fill in data.

Can someone please explain (possibly with an example) what I need to pass through setValue() to get a point on the line graph, and also what to pass through removeValue() so that a specific point on the graph could be removed?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Look up the javadoc, preferrably by googling

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve] that exhibits any problem you encounter. [`org.jfree.chart.demo.BarChartDemo1`](https://github.com/jfree/jfree-demos/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jfree/chart/demo/BarChartDemo1.java) is a good starting point.

Comment: The parameter required is a `Comparable` as explained here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html?is-external=true And you can see specifics on parameters from the jFreeChart API here: http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/org/jfree/data/category/DefaultCategoryDataset.html